# Converting PDF to Excel with C# .NET

Tags: c#, pdf

Basic question. I don't really have an issue with approaching the coding for converting PDF to .csv or excel file types, but I'm relatively new to Visual Studio and .NET development. What type of project should I create in Visual Studio to best execute this kind of task? I want a clean simple-to-use end product.

Should I make a console app? A windows app? What's the best way to package my final project and distribute it to people who aren't tech savvy (i.e. what's the best type of project to build with the simplest instructions to execute for an end user).

If it helps, my code will be searching for a specific directory to access the pdf files. This would mean that the end user would dump their pdf files in that directory. Assuming the end-user does not have Visual Studio on their PCs what is the best project type to pursue?

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Convert-PDF-file-to-Excel-f20be75e

Comment: This is a great link, much appreciated. Though, for the sake of learning/discussion I would like to get more of a response about my specific question. Looks like it can actually be done with just a console application though, which is very cool.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need VS Solution with two projects:

- a class library with business logic;
- a Console/Windows Forms/WPF App project.

The last depends on your client's wishes.